# Ruby Rails form_for for each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

any idea why this loop not working?

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= form_for(@bookedit) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :count, 'how many?' %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :count %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

on user controller:

```
@books = Book.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@book = Book.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@bookedit = Book.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @book})

@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

but when I use `find(:first` or `find(:last` it shows (but repeating the value) when it is :all it throws this error:

```
NoMethodError in Users#account 
undefined method `book_book_path' for #<#<Class:0x6ec5650>:0x6ec3448>
```

Thanks! im newb to ruby :D

Comment: What are you trying to do? `@books`, `@book` and `@bookedit` are all the same

Comment: I agree, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user should look like this -- >

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
#or @user = current_user
@books = @user.books
```

Your view should look like this -->

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :count, 'how many?' %><br />
        <%= f.number_field :count %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hi Johnny, the issue is with the instance variables we have in the controller -->

```
@books = Book.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@book = Book.where(user_id: current_user.id)
@bookedit = Book.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => @book})
```

From what I understand, User has_many books.

In this case `@book` isn't actually one instance of a book, but it's just the same as `@books`. Similarly, `@bookedit` is getting all Books with an Id, but it's not passing the id of the user.

Because of the association between users and books, you can get all the books I user has by

```
@books = @user.books
```

In your view, If we do

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
```

We iterate through all the books, and run a form_for that book